# The order of operators in JavaScript (|| ,&&)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, operator-precedence

I am reading the source code of Underscore.js, then something confused me:

```
// Its code, check the passed-in parameter obj 
_.isObject = function(obj) {
  var type = typeof obj;
  return type === 'function' || type === 'object' && !!obj;
};
```

I am confused about the operator order of expression.

I think the operator precedence in

```
return type === 'function' || type === 'object' && !!obj;
```

will be from `left` to `right`; I mean equal to :

```
return (type === 'function' ) || ( type === 'object' && !!obj);
```

if `type` equal `function`  return `true`; else operate `type === 'object' && !!obj`; if `type` equal `object` return `!!obj` ,same as `Boolean(obj)`; else return `false`;

I made some examples:

```
var a = alert(1) || alert(2) && alert(3);
alert(a); //result : 1, 2 undefined;


var a = alert(1) || alert(2) && 0;
alert(a); //result : 1, 2 undefined;
```

what confused me:

1. Why `!!obj` should exist? if we delete `!!obj`, code run as well.
2. the operator order of this code? I know `&&` operator are higher than `||`, so I guess `!!obj` effect when obj is null, but when I practice that is no what I want;

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Question is, since `null` **is** an object in Javascript, why would they want their `_.isObject` method to return `false` on `null`?

Comment: @connexo well, because in the vast majority of cases, you want to check if what you get is an object _with_ a value, rather than an object representing the absence of a value. Besides, were to actually make that argument for real (I am not sure if you're just playing devil's advocate here), then I'd point out that `null instanceof Object// false` while both `{}` and `function(){}` will return `true` for that. Thus, the `isObject` function is entirely consistent with those. Which, again, happens to be the most common use-case for such a check.

Answer (score 5):

They want to return `false` if the object is `null`. Usually when we need to know if something is an object, `null` is not what we're looking for. That's because trying to access `null`'s properties (`null[propName]` for example) would throw an error.

```js
console.log(typeof null);
```

The order of execution for the expression `type === 'function' || type === 'object' && !!obj;` is from left to right:

1. `type === 'function'` - if this is `true` the expression will return
   `true` without computing the rest
2. `type === 'object'` - if this is `false` the expression will return
   `false` without computing the last part
3. `!!obj` - `null` would return `false`, any other object would return `true`

The snippet demonstrates the flow:

```js
step(false, 1) || step(true, 2) && step(true, 3)

function step(ret, step) {
  console.log(step);
  
  return ret;
}
```

> Using `!!` we can cast values to booleans - So truthy values would be
> converted to true, for example `!!{} === true`, and falsy ones to
> false, for example `!!null === false`.

Comment: you should mention about `truthy-falsy`

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the expression is *not* read left to right, [`&&` has a slightly higher precedence than `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so it can be written either way -- `a && b || c` is identical to `c || a && b`. Operator precedence determines where parenthises should go in the expression, so `a && b || c` would be `(a && b) || c`. It's only within expressions *where every operator has the same precedence* that the operators are evaluated from left to right.

Regarding you're actual question -- in javascript, `typeof null === "object"`, so the `&& !!obj` part of the expression is to guard against `null` values evaluating to true.

Comment: In the case of OP, it's true that `a || b` is equivalent to `b || a` as every operand is a boolean. But it's not true for everything in JavaScript, as `"test" || "2"` returns `"test"` and `"2" || "test"` returns `"2"`.

Answer (score 1):

The last

```
!!obj
```

forces the return value to a boolean value and yes, it is necessary because of `typeof null` is `object`.

Comment: @dv, care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Just Reference to MDN's Operator Precedence.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

[image]

Precendence for `&&` is higher than `||`

`&&` first